# Why isn't this Python code properly assigning the DOM variable?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am fairly new to Python and totally new to XML operations in Python.  Here is a snippet of one of the XML files:

```
<!--created on 2023-08-21 06:58:42 - tinyMediaManager 4.3.13-->
<movie>
  <title>El Dorado</title>
  <originaltitle>El Dorado</originaltitle>
  <sorttitle/>
  ...
</movie>
```

I need to assign the  value to a variable.  The program assigns the null string instead of "El Dorado".  Here is the code:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
import glob
Directory = "/RAID/Server-Main/KODI/VideoDB/"

for InFile in glob.glob(Directory + "*.xnfo"):
    print(InFile)
    domtree = xml.dom.minidom.parse(InFile)
    group = domtree.documentElement
    Main = group.getElementsByTagName('movie')
    for name in Main:
        Title = name.getAttribute('title')
        print(Title)
```

I am not getting any error, and I know it s properly scanning in all the files, but the output is blank.

Edit: I did a little poking, and for some reason the program is never entering the for loop, meaning Main has no elements.  I do not understand this at all.

Comment: Typo? `name.getAttribute('title')` ("name" feels awkward for a node, but it's just naming)

Comment: Well, pft!  Obviously that is one issue, but I corrected the typo, and it still does not work.

Comment: Ok... I known nothing about Python...but: the [MRE] seem to be missing imports, example XML starts from "movie" node but code assumes that is second level node repeated multiple times, there are no attributes in the XML whatsoever but code tries to get some "title"  attribute (possibly you are looking for "node with name 'title'"), there is a good chance you did not check how to get text values of nodes using minidom (as crazy code to access `firstChild` missing completely)... Again I know nothing of python so comment could be well off-base - read at own risk.

Comment: Well, no, certainly not entirely.  I did make a mistake that caused the library to disappear.  'Sorry about that.  I have tried a couple of different approaches with the same result, so I don't know exactly how to respond to the rest.  I have tried a firstChild process in the loop, but the code is not getting that far.  The interpreter falls through the loop without executing any of the code in it, which implies the Main structure is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code can run normally.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
Directory = r"C:\Users\10696\Desktop\access\kkk.xml"
for InFile in [Directory]:
    print(InFile)
    domtree = ET.parse(InFile)
    Main = domtree.findall('movie')
    for name in Main:
        Title = name.find('title').text
        print(Title)
```

**kkk.xml**

```
<annotation>
  <movie>
    <title>El Dorado</title>
    <originaltitle>El Dorado</originaltitle>
    <sorttitle></sorttitle>
  </movie>
</annotation>
```